# I want to use the Power on and off button to Send an SMS

Tags: android

I am developing an App for a customer and his request is In Idle Mode. When a user double taps ( 2 short presses ) the Power on / Off button a preloaded SMS is sent.

When you are in Idle Mode, a short press on power button is to unlock and lock the phone, so when the phone is in locked or unlocked state, 2 short presses should send an SMS.

Can any help me with this query.

Thanks
Chirag

Answer (score 0):

To prevent two short taps u need to work at driver level. Android SDK only provides onClick and onLongClick listeners. Override onKeyDown and check KeyEvent need == KEYCODE_POWER.

Comment: I need the switch on / off key to work as is, i need to work as a SMS sender as well.